# Kotlin Script Engine throws "unresolved reference", even if the package and class is valid

Tags: kotlin

When using Kotlin's Script Engine, trying to import packages or use any class throws an "unresolved reference"

```
javax.script.ScriptException: error: unresolved reference: mrpowergamerbr
fun loritta(context: com.mrpowergamerbr.loritta.commands.CommandContext) {
                         ^
```

This doesn't happen when running the class within IntelliJ IDEA, however it does happen when running the class on production.

Answer (score 3):

While this [YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21443) is related to fat JARs, this also can happen if you aren't using fat JARs (loading all the libraries via the startup classpath option or the Class-Path manifest option)

To fix this, or you can all your dependencies on your startup script like this:

```
-Dkotlin.script.classpath=jar1:jar2:jar3:jar4
```

**Example:**

```
java -Dkotlin.script.classpath=libs/dependency1.jar:libs/dependency2.jar:yourjar.jar -jar yourjar.jar
```

Or, if you prefer, set the property via code, using your Class-Path manifest option.

```
val path = this::class.java.protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path
val jar = JarFile(path)
val mf = jar.manifest
val mattr = mf.mainAttributes
// Yes, you SHOULD USE Attributes.Name.CLASS_PATH! Don't try using "Class-Path", it won't work!
val manifestClassPath = mattr[Attributes.Name.CLASS_PATH] as String

// The format within the Class-Path attribute is different than the one expected by the property, so let's fix it!
// By the way, don't forget to append your original JAR at the end of the string!
val propClassPath = manifestClassPath.replace(" ", ":") + ":Loritta-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"

// Now we set it to our own classpath
System.setProperty("kotlin.script.classpath", propClassPath)
```

While I didn't test this yet, in another unrelated answer it seems you can also supply your own classpath if you initialize the KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine object yourself (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44796842/7271796))